# What is meant by saying that someone feels possessed by something?

Tags: meaning

> I 
>   suffered an attack of sneezing, my skull hurt, and I had a fever, but I felt possessed by a strength and determination 
>   I'd never  had at any age or  for any reason.

The text as it now stands seems to suggest that the narrator is possessed by the feeling rather than having possession of it.
Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English (v. 5) has the following similar combination:

> be possessed of something:
>     (literary)   to have a particular quality, ability etc :
>   She was possessed of a fine and original mind.

Does "be possessed by something" have the same meaning as preceding sentence or does it have another meaning?

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_possession.  I suspect a figurative usage here.  If a body can be possessed by an evil demon that makes it speak in non-sense and its head to spin around, why can't it also be possessed by a good spirit that provides "strength and determination."

Comment: "Possessed by" implies someone has been taking over by an outside source or force that is not under their own control - and in your example is stated clearly by the phrase "I'd never had at any age or for any reason".

Comment: I can't see any mileage in '... felt possessed of ...', even though 'She felt she had a reasonable mind' works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

‘Possessed of’ and ‘possessed by’ mean different things.

***Possessed of*** essentially identifies ***the owner of*** something, applying to external possessions or personal qualities.

***Possessed by*** means something like ***in the grip of***:  helplessly controlled by either an external will (e.g. a demon) or an overriding personal motivation (e.g. vengefulness).

The connotation is usually negative, but it need not be:  one might equally be possessed by hilarity, or by a compulsion to philanthropy.

*The American Heritage Guide to Contemporary Usage and Style* (Houghton Mifflin, 2005, p365) explains this distinction helpfully, although I think that this is *not* a territorial usage  (it occurs in British English as well, although ‘possessed of’ might be regarded as archaic or pretentious):

> Curiously, although the form *possessed* is that of a past participle
>   or adjective, it can have the meaning of an *active* participle as
>   well, becoming synonymous with ‘possessing’ in the sense of owning
>   something or having some property.  In this case, however, the
>   preposition *of* must be used: *She was possessed of a large estate*. 
>   *That child is possessed of a sharp tongue*.  Furthermore, the prepositional phrase beginning with *of* cannot be omitted in this
>   context without an alteration of meaning.  Thus the sentence *She was
>   possessed* can only mean that she was possessed *with* or *by*
>   something, not that she possessed something herself.

Paul Brians puts it [less technically but more succinctly](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/possessed.html), in what appears to be an extract from [Common Errors in English Usage](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Common-Errors-English-Usage-Edition/dp/1590282639) (3rd edn, William James and co, 2013):

> If you own a yacht, you’re possessed of it. If a demon takes over your
>   body, you’re possessed by it.

Comment: 'possessed of' is archaic sounding, and is not likely to be used even in current formal writing. The preferred manner is easily distinguished: 'is possessed of' -> 'possesses' or at worst 'has possession of'